# Can miners freely chose the order of transactions within a block?

Tags: transactions, mining, blocks

Can miners freely choose the order of transactions within a block or are there any restrictions like the transactions need to be sorted by gas price?

Answer (score 1):

For the most part. The only stipulation is that transactions from the same address must be executed by ascending nonce - e.g. if I send 2 transactions, one with nonce 3 and one with nonce 4, the miner must order the nonce 3 tx before the nonce 4 tx.